# Use email to validate post, not unlike craigslist

Tags: 7, emails, nodes

I'd like for anonymous users to be able to post nodes to my site. By default their post is unpublished, but when they submit it, the site sends an email with a verification URL. When they revisit the site with that URL they can then publish their node.

Call this the 'craigslist model.' :-)

Restating: I want users to be able to publish their own node anonymously, by linking out of an email.

I've been unable to find a module or setting that does this, and I thought I'd ask before diving into code.

Update: Found this unmaintained Drupal 5 project: [Anonymous publishing](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing).

Similar question: [How can anonymous users be allowed to post while still maintaining content integrity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53470/how-can-anonymous-users-be-allowed-to-post-while-still-maintaining-content-integ)

Comment: There is a thread at http://drupal.org/node/1957644 to see if we can't get an active discussion going about the newly revived Anonymous Publishing module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Rules module, but you'll have to write a [custom rule](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-custom-rules-how-write-your-own-events-conditions-actions-and-custom-object-custom-token) to grab the email from the submitted node and send a verification link to the email address. You could also do this with a custom function through [hook_entity_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7).

For the verification link you could do use [drupal_hmac_base64()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_hmac_base64/7) to create a url-safe hash of the content of the post or of the node + timestamp + email or something like that.

Then you can create a custom menu to fire a callback function that takes arguments from the verification link to publish the node if the verification link is correct.

Comment: OK, so this is some basic pointing-in-the-direction-of type advice, and that's appreciated. And the answer really is: No such easy solution, so you'll have to roll one. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @paul-m did you ever create a complete solution based on the rules module acouch suggested? If so, that code and how you accomplished that would be great to have as one of the answers to the thread.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [Anonymous Publishing](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) for this.

There is now a Drupal 7 port that can be downloaded.  It is still in development, but the "Craigslist model" for anonymous publishing has been working on my test-site and seems to be stable.  I am now looking for others that are willing to test the code, and confirm that it is ready for a full release.

Disclosure; I an the maintainer of  [Anonymous Publishing](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module for this: When a user posts a node, an email with a link to the node is sent to the admin, or a user role that you want to revise the node.

Using this method will save you much time than diving into code.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want users to be able to publish their own node anonymously, by linking out of an email.