# How can anonymous users be allowed to post while still maintaining content integrity?

Tags: 7, rules, users

A little background: As you see on http://charlotte.ebayclassifieds.com, if you click 'post an ad' and then choose a category, you can fill out the form and submit content without having to sign up.  This is all done and managed by sending validation emails to the email address field which, when clicked, allow a user to manipulate their content.

Can similar functionality be achieved in Drupal. I don't mind writing a module, but before I do, I want to make sure I am not reinventing the wheel.

I have a Drupal based local classifieds site for my community at http://www.gastonia.com.  The site is growing in anonymous traffic, but few users are signing up to post. After a couple feedback loops with the community, almost everyone is saying that the one barrier to entry is having to sign up for an account, check email, validate, figure out how to navigate to post an ad, etc - indeed there are 7 steps necessary to go through before an ad actually gets published.  It's too much..

We have reworked the architecture to be able to get it down to two clicks - click to post, then click to save. More specifically, a user clicks on 'Add content' and the node/add form pops up (there is now only one content type in the new architecture); Then, when they are done, they click save.

Originally I thought about the [Inline Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_registration) module, but it is still in DEV and the logic really is not there to support if the user comes back to post again with the same email address (without loggin in). I could alter it, but then we are back to writing a module.

I also thought about Rules - could rules handle similar functionality as the ebayclassifieds site or what I am trying to do? It would all be based on an email filed in the node/add form (CRUD functionality).

What direction or recipe would you suggest to achieve the functionality? Of course the ultimate goal here is to allow anon users to post; create an account behind the scenes for future use; allow use of the anon form even for users with emails that already have accounts (and assign content accordingly.) all while maintaining the security (from spam, bots) that is afforded by having a user sign up and authenticate an account.

EDIT: 4/1/2013
Gisle Hannemyr has revived the [Anonymous Publishing module](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing) which is very close to achieving the goals described here and in other posts. Please take part in the the thread to provide some community feedback as to how to make the module bug free and better:
http://drupal.org/node/1957644

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/use-email-to-validate-post-not-unlike-craigslist

Comment: Would OAuth/OpenID be too much for your users? Janrain makes it a breeze to login.

Comment: I have never heard about Janrain, but I do like the idea of people using other accounts to login. Like here on DSE I use my google account always. As simple as that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with rules alone.

You need to alter the submission form in order to capture the verification email address, and you also need some logic to ban spammers and recognise returning visitors.

I am the maintainer of a project named [Anonymous Publishing](http://drupal.org/project/anonymous_publishing). It looks as if this module does what you want.

It still in development, but a Drupal 7 version has been used at several of my production sites without any issues. Please check it out.

You may also want to look at the answers under [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25194/use-email-to-validate-post-not-unlike-craigslist).

Comment: Thanks for that, will spend some time checking out the code!

Comment: I created a thread at http://drupal.org/node/1957644 to see if we can't get an active discussion going about that module. Thanks for reviving that.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved something similar to this on a recent project by creating a new menu callback – something like `example.com/anon_user` – which provides a form that doubles as a login and a registration form. This allows the user to very quickly go through the registration process OR to login without making them perform too many actions. It's actually been received fairly well.

Here's some simplified code to demonstrate this:

```
function example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Don't let authenticated users use this form.
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid != 0) {
    return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
  }

  // Let the user know what they can do.
  $form['intro']['#markup'] = "Already have an account? Login here. Don't have an account? Enter your email address and create a password and we'll setup an account for you.");

  $form['login'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    'user_email' => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#title' => t('E-mail Address'),
    ),
    'user_pass' => array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#title' => t('Password'),
    ),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Continue',
  );

  return $form;
}
```

Validate it however you need:

```
function example_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['user_email'])) {
    form_set_error('user_email', 'You entered an invalid email address.');
  }
}
```

In the submit handler, we need to figure out if this email already exists and attempt to log them in. If it doesn't exist, try to create an account for them.

```
function example_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;

  // Does this account already exist?
  if ($user_name = db_query("SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE mail = :mail", array(':mail' => $form_state['values']['user_email']))->fetchField()) {
    // Attempt to log them in.
    if ($account_id = user_authenticate($user_name, $form_state['values']['user_pass'])) {
      drupal_set_message('You have been logged in.');
      $user = user_load($account_id);
    } else {
      drupal_set_message('You have an account here, but you entered the wrong password.', 'error');
    }
  } 

  // Create the account.
  else {
    // Use their email address as their username. Or handle this with a more complex login form.
    $account_name = str_replace('@', '_', $form_state['values']['user_email']);
    $account = user_save(null, array(
      'name' => $account_name,
      'pass' => $form_state['values']['user_pass'],
      'mail' => $form_state['values']['user_email'],
      'init' => $form_state['values']['user_email'],
      'status' => 1,
      'access' => REQUEST_TIME,
    ));
    // Log 'em in to their new account.
    drupal_set_message('Your account has been created and you have been successfully logged in!');
    );
    $user = user_load(user_authenticate($account->name, $form_state['values']['user_pass']));
  }
}
```

This is a pretty simple example. You could add password requirements, password confirmation via a 2nd field, a username field, better warnings, etc. The more restrictions the longer the process, so that's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can go about lowering the "registration hurdle":

- use Facebook connect to allow login with a facebook account (I use and
  like [fboauth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) module)
- there are other social login modules that
  support google, paypal, yahoo, openid, etc.
- you can change the registration option to not require email
  confirmations.

To answer your last question:

> What direction or recipe would you suggest to achieve the functionality? Of course the ultimate goal here is to allow anon users to post; create an account behind the scenes for future use; allow use of the anon form even for users with emails that already have accounts (and assign content accordingly.) all while maintaining the security (from spam, bots) that is afforded by having a user sign up and authenticate an account.

I suggest to use a "anonymous node registration" feature (I can share code if you like). I adds "name" and "email address" fields to a "node add" form.

If the email doesn't exist already it will create a new user account. It uses the firstname to create the username and adds numbers if necessary to make it unique.

The password is set randomly and displayed to the user after submitting the node with a link to change the password.

Also, email confirmations won't prevent spam bots from signing up. I highly recommend the [spambot](http://drupal.org/project/spambot) module.

Comment: You mentioned code you could share. Then you wrote a module for your own use already? I would like to take a look at it if you'd like to put it online somewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's also this module now too: [Create and Register](http://drupal.org/project/create_and_reg)